# java doesn't work from cmd

Tags: java, command-line

I spent about 5 hours googling, but can't find the solution.

I try to install jperf on all my computers,and all but 2 install perfectly. But those two I can't force to run.

One is XP Pro (like half of my computers), second one is XP home (like other half of my computers)

When I run jperf.bat - the command line window appears and disappears. Then nothing happens.

java.exe is in path - typing java shows the correct result.

**edited again**

now i can see the errors:

```
C:\JPERF-~1.2>java -classpath jperf.jar;lib\forms-1.1.0.jar;lib\jcommon-1.0.10.j
ar;lib\jfreechart-1.0.6.jar;lib\swingx-0.9.6.jar net.nlanr.jperf.JPerf
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesk
top/swingx/JXTaskPaneContainer
        at net.nlanr.jperf.JPerf$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTaskPaneConta
iner
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 15 more
```

So, what can we do now? What is missing???

Comment: Open a command prompt into the directory where you have jperf.bat. Then run it from the command line and you should see a clearer error

Comment: question edited: no errors

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using javaw rather than java.  I understand javaw is used when you DON'T want any diagnostic output.  Try running with java (as opposed to javaw) from the command line as suggested earlier.

Comment: Very good sugesstion (i don't know about difference between java and javaw) - now i'm iluminated ;D

Answer (score 0):

Try running the batch file from a command prompt - you can then see the error messages.  If necessary enter a sub-shell (i.e. type cmd).  Might be a 32 bit / 64 bit Java problem - anyway once you see the error messages it is usually obvious what to do.

Answer (score 0):

It could be you are trying to run a 64 bit app on a 32 bit JVM.

Failing that, I am guessing that swingx-0.9.6.jar is either not present where you say it is or it doesn't contain:

```
org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTaskPaneContainer
```

You can inspect the jar using WinZip.  Why did you choose this jar (presumably there was a reference somewhere)?  If it works on some machines and not others I would assume the jars are different (even though they have the same name).  Try copying one of the working jars to one of machines that is hosed and try again, but make sure it is not a 32 v. 64 bit problem.

Comment: I just unpack the jperf.zip and install java 7u45 from sun. Everywhere works but two machines